# Capture SSL Certificate using Android Volley

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, android-volley

I implemented SSL Pinning in Android using Volley Library. Now, If I proxy my requests through a Proxy tool like Burp, ZAProxy etc. the https call fails and my execution goes to the error function (ErrorListener) in the below code.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        textView.setText(response);
                        Toast.makeText(context, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                    textView.setText(error.networkResponse.headers.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
```

Now when I access `error.networkResponse` , it gives my NULL. I googled a lot of things and tried fetching it from the error response but didn't get anything useful.

Is it possible to get some information about the proxy tool or the SSL certificate sent by the proxy tool?

Comment: Can you try the same without using volley to make sure it is happening with valley.

Comment: Tried to do that, but no output. I am not sure even if it's possible or not.